# Cannot use angular to call web api in cshtml

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have to add an AngularJs control to my `cshtml` file in a project but as I couldn't make it work I tried to create a simple test application, and now it seems that even this simple app (including only an app module and a controller) is not working!

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('testApp', []);
});
```

**GetProductsCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('testApp.controllers', []); //this is supposed to go in a separate file
angular.module('testApp.controllers')
    .controller("GetProductsCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.greetings = "hi";
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:54327/api/products"
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });
    });
```

**ProductsController.cs**

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{//inside the web api project and running on http://localhost:54327/
    Product[] products = new Product[]
   {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
   };
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(product);
    }
}
```

**usage**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/common/GetProductsCtrl.js"></script>
<div class="row" ng-app="testApp">
    <div>
        Here I want to add the control.
        {{1+1}} @*even this is not evaluated by angular!(it was working)*@
        <ul ng-controller="GetProductsCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="product in products">
                {{product.Name}} : $ {{product.Price}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular/app.js"
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can guess is that Bundle will try rename your $http provider.
So try  .controller("GetProductsCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http){
}] instead.

Comment: Actually one of the first things that I've tried was to inject these `http` service but no success. The funny thing is that even without any controller now angular is not evaluating my expression {{1+1}}.

Comment: Open Developer tool on your browser to see what the actual error is may help.

Comment: great idea. It says angular is not defined! it seems that there is a problem with loading angular (at least I interpret it this way)